# MSWmi_PnPDeviceId in WMI of a specific device

Tags: c#, wmi, webcam

How do I get the PnpDevice Id of a specific device? for a webcam or soundcard?
The below code gets me PNPIds of all devices but I'm unable to identify which id is for what device.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", 
                    "SELECT * FROM MSWmi_PnPDeviceId"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("MSWmi_PnPDeviceId instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Active: {0}", queryObj["Active"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("PnPDeviceId: {0}", queryObj["PnPDeviceId"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PnPDeviceId which you will get from instance of MSWmi_PnPDeviceId can be used to query Win32_PnPEntity (namespace ROOT\CIMV2) class instances to get more details of device. e.g. `SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID=PnPDeviceId`

Win32_PnPEntity class has around 26 properties which will give more details of device.
PFB one such screenshot.
[image]